# Rigging Car Suspension

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

How would I set something like this up simply? This video demonstrates Rigacar's Suspension. The hierarchy is too complex for me to understand what is happening. When any of the Dampers move, it rotates the Suspension.

https://youtu.be/z9zRzFb6hCs

Thank you!

[image]